# edit legend values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot like below. It was created with this command:

```
popanim <-  ggplot(data =  pop2, aes(
  x = age1,
  y = ifelse(gender == 1, -pop_rel, pop_rel),
  fill = gender, 
  group = district
)) +
  geom_col() +
  # facet_wrap( ~ country) +
  coord_flip() +
  transition_states(district, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  labs(title = 'district: {closest_state}')+
  xlab("age") + ylab("population") #HERE


anim_pop <- animate(popanim, nframes = 50, renderer = gifski_renderer("gganimate.gif"))

anim_save(anim_pop = anim_pop, filename ="//pyramidd.gif")
```

Now next thing I want to do is to modify the legend value from 1 into `male` and 2 into `female`

[image]

I have tried `scale_fill_discret` but it does not work

Comment: `pop2  <- pop2 %>% mutate(gender = ifelse(gender == 1, 'male', 'female'))` ?

Comment: I did this but it changes the form of population pyramid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Male", "Female"))`. Here I show a reproducible example since you have not provided reproducible data (which is always recommended):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
        geom_col() +
        coord_flip() +
        scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Male", "Female", "Other"))
```

[image]